# pairing items from an index in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame glob as shown

```
 a  b    c         Index Def
 3  4   "good"      1    ANGLO
 1  3   "great"     2    ORTHO
 4  1   "average"   3    TEEN
 2  3   "ok"        4    SPLEEN
```

Index is the index and I want to replace column a and b contents with the contents of Def that lies in the alternate cell to the corresponding Index.I want a resulting data frame as such

```
TEEN  SPLEEN  "good"
ANGLO TEEN    "great"
SPLEEN ANGLO  "average"
ORTHO  TEEN    "ok"
```

It would be very helpful if you could provide the code using 1)for loop 2)apply

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reproducible data. That is given along with expected output.

Comment: I am using this to get the value corresponding to ''a'' but this does not work                                                                                                      for(i in 1:4)
{
  for(j in 1:length(df$Index))
  {
    if(df$a[i]==df$Index[j])
      
    {
    df$res1[i]<-df$def[j]
    
    
    }
    
  }
  
  
}

Answer (score 2):

Is this the solution you want?

```
df$a <- df$Def[df$Index[df$a]]
df$b <- df$Def[df$Index[df$b]]
df
       a      b       c Index    Def
1   TEEN SPLEEN    good     1  ANGLO
2  ANGLO   TEEN   great     2  ORTHO
3 SPLEEN  ANGLO average     3   TEEN
4  ORTHO   TEEN      ok     4 SPLEEN
```

You can get rid of the last two columns using:

```
df <- df[, c('a', 'b', 'c')]
df
       a      b       c
1   TEEN SPLEEN    good
2  ANGLO   TEEN   great
3 SPLEEN  ANGLO average
4  ORTHO   TEEN      ok
```

Comment: Thanks. But as i said I want to do this using for loop and apply.